# Elegant way to select <tr> when a child <a> is active

Tags: ember.js

Suppose I have the following partial template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_folderList">
  <table id="folder-list">
    <thead>
      <tr class="PLEASE_MAKE_ME_ACTIVE_IF_SELECTED_ROW">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each folder in controller}}
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{#linkTo "folder" folder }} 
              <i class="icon-folder-close"></i> {{ folder.folder_name }} 
            {{/linkTo}}
          </td>
          <td style="padding-left: 15px;">
            {{ prettyDate folder.created_date}}
          </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Notice the class I've added to the table row element. How can I add an "active" class to this row when it's child link is the active link? Ember automatically adds the active link when the current route matches the element in the collection. I'm trying to find the elegant, "Ember way" of doing this without resorting to jQuery hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'd still like to see an answer to the question as I originally stated it, the workaround I went with for now is not to use tables at all. I'm already using Bootstrap based CSS layouts for the rest of my site, so I decided to use a fluid layout instead of tables:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_folderList">
  <div id="folder-list">
        <div class="container-fluid list-header">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span5">Name</div>
            <div class="span7">Date Created</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {{#each folder in controller}}
        {{#linkTo "folder" folder }} 
          <div class="container-fluid list-item">
            <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span5">
                <i class="icon-folder-close"></i> {{ folder.folder_name }} 
              </div>
              <div class="span7">
                {{ prettyDate folder.created_date}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        {{/linkTo}}
      {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

This allows me to wrap the whole "row" with the anchor using {{#linkTo}} and style the whole row accordingly.

Comment: One thing I should add is that while this works, it might produce undesired behavior on mobile or other smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bindAttr` to toggle the classname. For example if you hold the state in an `isSelected` property in your controller then in the template.

```
<tr {{bindAttr class='isSelected:active'}}>
```

Where `active` is the css class name.

Comment: the state is being managed by Ember in this case automatically though, which is what I'm wrestling with. Ember is adding the "active" class to the links automatically. So how can I access that state in an attribute binding?

Comment: I see. That would be tough. The computation of the `active` property is inside LinkView. A better question might be, "How to bind to a property of generated view from another related view?". If you can get someone to answer that you will effectively get the answer you need.